# how to pass compilation flags when compiling ruby with rbenv?

Tags: ruby, compilation

I saw [this post](http://alisnic.net/blog/making-your-ruby-fly/) explaining how to compile rubies for rvm with `-O3` and so on, but how do i do the equivalent with rbenv? in particular i want `-O0 -g3` (no optimization, and highest debugging level)

Answer (score 2):

You can export `CFALGS` or pass additional configuration flags to the `ruby-build` via the `CONFIGURE_OPTS` env variable. However, this might be a case where [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) is actually impeding you. Since `rbenv install` simply calls [ruby-build $DEFINITION ~/.rbenv/versions/$DEFINITION](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/blob/master/bin/rbenv-install#L81) and `rbenv` can use any Ruby in `~/.rbenv/versions/`, you could configure Ruby manually:

```
$ CFLAGS="-O0 -ggdb" ./configure --prefix=~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-debug
$ make
$ make install
```

Comment: this didnt work :( The 'make install' did not copy it into the ~/.rbenv folder

Answer (score -1):

This [page](http://albertogrespan.com/blog/installing-ruby-the-right-way-on-os-x-using-rbenv/) says you can do it this way:

> If you want to compile Ruby with your preferred versions of OpenSSL, Readline and LibYAML you just need to export or append RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS to your installation command.

I haven't tried it yet, but I will when I get to my dev machine.